# Delete entities by partition key in Azure Tables

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

I am currently migrating web configs to Azure Tables. I have a selection of entities sectioned by partition key.

Instead of updating these config entities when changes needed to be made, I was wondering if it's possible to delete all entities based on their specific partition key and then adding them again based on their partition key?

I can't seem to find anything that would indicate that I can within the documentation or within other sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if it's possible to delete all entities based on their
> specific partition key and then adding them again based on their
> partition key?

If you're looking to delete all entities in a partition (i.e. having same partition key value) with a single command, it is not possible. You will need to delete each entity separately.

You can however speed up the operation by using `Entity Group Transaction` where you can delete up to 100 entities in a single operation. You can also use entity group operation to create 100 entities having same partition key in a single operation.

You can learn more about the entity group transaction here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/performing-entity-group-transactions.